# Spring batch, handle failed files again, skip successfully handled

Tags: spring-batch

How to ideologically correct organize file handling?

I have a folder for new files (NEW), folder for old files (OLD), a folder for failed files (FAIL). New file puts in NEW, then if the handling was correct, the file goes to OLD, if the handling was failed, the file goes to ERR. Then we take this file again and correcting it and put in NEW if all ok file goes to OLD if failed goes to ERR. And repeat again and again.

I have job with constant name "fileHandlingJob", in job i have some steps: "extract", "handling", "utilize", and i have job parameters: "filePath", "fileName".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you state that uniqueness criteria of file - it's file's name, then you are on right way.

If job was in state FAILED (ERR folder) then you can retrigger it with same set of parameters. If job was COMPLETED - you can't run it again. Spring batch will complain.

You can ensure this behaviour by having unique file name as Job's parameter. So no other job could be triggered with same file name. Spring batch will simply prevent this. 
Second parameter `filePath` can be additional non-unique parameter.

```
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder()                
            .addString("fileName", "myfile.xml", true)
            .addDate("filePath", "C:\new\myfile.xml", false);
```

`true`/`false` here means whether parameter is unique or not.